# How to iterate over a vec in Rust and make changes?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to build a task manager with Rust for practice.

I want to have an archived tasks sections, and so this is my task manager struct:

```
pub struct TaskManager {
    tasks: Vec<Task>,
    archived_tasks: Vec<Task>,
}
```

I have functions to make tasks and archived tasks public:

```
impl TaskManager {
    pub fn tasks(&self) -> &Vec<Task> {
        &self.tasks
    }

    pub fn tasks_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Vec<Task> {
        &mut self.tasks
    }

    pub fn archived_tasks(&self) -> &Vec<Task> {
        &self.archived_tasks
    }

    pub fn archived_tasks_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Vec<Task> {
        &mut self.archived_tasks
    }
}
```

Then, I have a function to archive a task that works:

```
impl TaskManager {
    pub fn archive_task(&mut self, idx: usize) -> Result<(), String> {
        match self.tasks.get(idx) {
            Some(_) => {
                self.archived_tasks.push(self.tasks.remove(idx));
                Ok(())
            },
            None => Err("No task with that index".to_string())
        }
    }
}
```

And then... the borrow checker. I can't do this or anything like it, so I can't iterate over my tasks and call `archive_task`:

```
impl App {
    fn archive_done_tasks(&mut self) {
        for (idx, task) in self.task_manager.tasks().iter().enumerate() {
            if task.done() {
                self.task_manager.archive_task(idx);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course the compiler complains:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `self.task_manager` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
   --> src/app.rs:194:17
    |
192 |         for (idx, task) in self.task_manager.tasks().iter().enumerate() {
    |                            --------------------------------------------
    |                            |
    |                            immutable borrow occurs here
    |                            immutable borrow later used here
193 |             if task.done() {
194 |                 self.task_manager.archive_task(idx);
    |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

Is there something I'm missing or what I'm trying to do is not possible?

Comment: Tip: Don't. You're going to end up fighting against the mutable borrow checker. Instead use [`partition()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.partition) to split a singular list into two parts. You can then "archive" one set, and reassign to the `tasks` property with the other.

Comment: Note that [you want to return `&[T]`, not `&Vec<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-string-vec-or-box-as-a-function).

Comment: @tadman Sounds nice. But where should I use partition()?

Comment: Sometimes in Rust it's better to dismantle an object and reassemble it than it is to try and hack around on it in-place. In this case, maybe `fn archive_done_tasks(self) -> Self` so you can smash it apart completely if necessary. The `partition()` operation can split into retained/archived tasks, and you can then reassemble with the retained set.

Comment: Alternatively you could sort your list on retain/archive status so all the archived entries are at the end, then if `any` are `done()`, `split_off` those entries which you can `append` to the other vec.

Comment: @tadman an other option is to use `into_iter()` and `filter_map` to either move items and return `None`, or keep the item, collect-ing back into the collection at the end. With in-place collect it should be able to reuse the original allocation when collecting, so it's essentially an in-place filter-and-move, similar to `retain` except it moves non-retained elements out of the collection instead of dropping them.

Comment: @tadman `drain` might be more applicable than `split_off`, as it can move items directly from one vec to the next instead of allocating an intermediate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using index and allocating memory for them, I propose another solution using iterators:

```rust
/// This will require nightly channel
#![feature(extract_if)]
struct Task {
    done: bool
}

impl Task {
    pub fn done(&self) -> bool {self.done}
}

pub struct TaskManager {
    tasks: Vec<Task>,
    archived_tasks: Vec<Task>,
}

impl TaskManager {
    pub fn archive_done_tasks(&mut self) {
        let iter = self.tasks.extract_if(|x| x.done());
        self.archived_tasks.extend(iter);
    }
}

struct App {
    task_manager: TaskManager,
}

impl App {
    fn archive_done_tasks(&mut self) {
        self.task_manager.archive_done_tasks()
    }
}


fn main() {
    let mut app = App{task_manager: TaskManager{tasks: vec![], archived_tasks: vec![]}};
    app.archive_done_tasks();
    println!("Done")
}
```

If you want to use stable channel you can do its equivalent:

```rust
/// Stable channel
struct Task {
    done: bool
}

impl Task {
    pub fn done(&self) -> bool {self.done}
}

pub struct TaskManager {
    tasks: Vec<Task>,
    archived_tasks: Vec<Task>,
}

impl TaskManager {
    pub fn archive_done_tasks(&mut self) {
        let mut i = 0;
        while i < self.tasks.len() {
            if self.tasks[i].done() {
                let val = self.tasks.remove(i);
                self.archived_tasks.push(val);
            } else {
                i += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

struct App {
    task_manager: TaskManager,
}

impl App {
    fn archive_done_tasks(&mut self) {
        self.task_manager.archive_done_tasks()
    }
}


fn main() {
    let mut app = App{task_manager: TaskManager{tasks: vec![], archived_tasks: vec![]}};
    app.archive_done_tasks();
    println!("Done")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message points out, you cannot get a mutable reference to task_manager if it is already borrowed.

In fact, this compiler error prevented a bug in your code.

Were this allowed, `archive_task` would be removing items from the `tasks` vec while `archive_done_tasks` is iterating over it. This would cause some nasty errors, but thankfully rust prevents this type of issue.

A common pattern to avoid adding or removing items is to break the logic into two passes

1. Identify the indexes to be removed
2. Remove the indexes

Keeping in mind that as elements are being removed, it changes the index of every element to the right.

```
let mut indices: Vec<usize> = tm.tasks().iter().enumerate()
    .filter(|(_, task)| task.done())
    .map(|(idx, _)| idx)
    .collect();
indices.sort();
for (offset, idx) in indices.into_iter().enumerate() {
    tm.archive_task(idx-offset);
}
```

If you are able to move the logic entirely inside of TaskManager, you could use an even simpler solution using [`partition`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.partition)

```
    pub fn archive_task(&mut self, idx: usize) {
        let tasks = std::mem::take(&mut self.tasks);
        let (done, in_progress): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = tasks.into_iter().partition(|task| task.done());
        self.tasks = in_progress;
        self.archived_tasks.extend(done);
    }
```

Comment: I tried moving the logic inside of TaskManager then using partition, but Rust compiler won't let me `self.tasks.into_iter().partition()` without implementing Clone for Task and cloning. Is there some workaround that doesn't need cloning?

Comment: You can use `std::mem::take`. I updated the answer